# subbasis generating usual topology

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove that  $S := \{ (-\infty, b) : b\in\Bbb R \}\cup \{ (a, ∞) : a\in\Bbb R\}$ generates the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.

I am trying to show that this set generates the usual basis. However, when I take finite intersections of sets of $S$, I get one of the following sets: $\{0\},\;(a,b),\;(-\infty, b)$ and $(a,\infty )$.  My understanding is that sets in the form of $(a,b)$ generate the basis for the usual topology and that null set is a subset of every set, but what do we do about these "extraneous"sets $(-\infty, b)$ and $(a,\infty)$?  They are not part of the usual basis that generates the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every open set with respect to the usual topology $\tau$ is an union of intervals of the type $(a,b)$, with $a<b$. Therefore, since $S$ contains each such interval, the topology $\tau_S$ generated by $S$ contains $\tau$. But then, since each element of $S$ belongs to $\tau$, $\tau_S\subset\tau$, and therefore $\tau_S=\tau$.

Comment: Thank you Jose.  That's concise and very clear.  As an aside does the subbase above generate the usual base  ie intervals in the form of (a,b) or does it not since it has the extra infinite ray intervals.  Or does it generate another base ie (a,b) union (-∞, b) union (a, ∞) and that is another base from the usual base but also generates the usual topology.

Comment: Since each such interval is the intersection of two elements of $S$, yes, it does.

Comment: Thanks.  So then (-∞, b) is an element of the usual basis.

Comment: What *is* the “usual basis”?

Comment: β = { (a,b) ⊆ R : a < b }

Comment: Then, no, $(-\infty,b)$ is not an element of the usual basis.

Comment: β1 = { (a,b) ⊆ R : a < b }     β2 = { (a,b) ⊆ R : a < b } U ((-∞, b) : b ⊆ R) U ((a,∞,) : a ⊆ R)             Do they both generate the usual topology

Comment: Yes, both of them generate the usual topology.

Comment: ok, now I fully understand  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many "generating sets" for a topology. A collection of subsets $\mathcal{A}$ of a set $X$ generates the topology $\tau$ if the smallest (in inclusion sense) topology on $X$ that contains $X$.

There are two types of generating collections, in a way: a base (where we "only" need to take unions of them to get all open sets) and a subbase (where we also take finite intersections to create a "base", so they're often more "economical").

In your case, sets of the form $(-\infty, a)$ are open in $\tau$, they are clearly unions of sets in the standard base: $(-\infty, a)= \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N^+} (a-(n+2), a-n)$, e.g. and similarly for sets of the form $(a, +\infty)$. They are not members of the standard base, but all sets in the standard base are in a any topology that contains them because $(a,b)=(-\infty, b) \cap (a, +\infty)$ and open sets are closed under finite intersections.

So if we have a known generating set $\mathcal{B}$ for $\tau$ and we have another candidate $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \tau$ of which we know we can make (by finite intersections and all unions) all members of $\mathcal{B}$, we must have that $\mathcal{A}$ also generates $\tau$. (The topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$ is at most $\tau$ (because they're already open in $\tau$, and we take the minimal topology containing the family) and at least $\tau$ (because we get all members of $\mathcal{B}$ which is generating for $\tau$)).

Comment: Thanks Henno, that makes it a lot clearer.

Comment: So if we have a basis that generates a particular topology and then we add to that basis sets which are open in that topology then the new basis will still generate the same topology.

Comment: @AlexM. Yes indeed. These are in a way redundant. We often want generating sets to be small or have a simple form.